# Strengthening the low amplitude signal using Matlab WITHOUT changing the original shape of the signal

Tags: matlab

I have a problem in signal processing with Matlab.
I would like to analyze some signal using Matlab but there is a huge difference between the amplitude of signals. 
The problem is that the shape of the signal in low amplitude is similar to the shape of the signal in high amplitude. but to analyse the signal, I have to have same range amplitude signal.
how can I have that without destroying the shape and properties of the signal?
Sorry I couldn't send an example plot to clear that.

Comment: Have you tried any kind of correlation techniques?  What about cross correlation?  http://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/xcorr.html.  Correlation in this case will compare the shape of the signal more than the amplitude.  It's looking for similarities.

Comment: As it is, your question is not a good fit for the site, because it is too broad. See [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2):

Something like:

```
signal1;
signal2;

signal1=(signal1- min(signal1(:))/(max(signal1(:))-min(signal1(:)))
signal2=(signal2- min(signal2(:))/(max(signal2(:))-min(signal2(:)))
% Now both signals are 0-1 range
```

Without more information this is all what we can offer!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The problem is that I have a big data( for example: 10 hours of ECG data) and this amplitude change is happened many times during the whole data. Therefore, I cannot separate signals easily.

Comment: So whats your problem? separate data or normalize data? what is what you want to achieve? your problems are a bit ambiguous, we dont know what you want @Ana

Comment: Normalise data! I need even amplitude data without changing the shape of the original signal. For example, I need to strengthen a heart beat with low amplitude to high amplitude one keeping its original shape

Comment: @Ana Yes, and this code does that. If you run it now all the code is 0-1 range, normalized. Why is not working? The size of the data should not matter as long as your computer can handle it.

Comment: I think I described my problem so bad!

Comment: @Ana I think you did... Thats why you got 3 downvotes actually

Comment: I think I described my problem so bad! I have a single file which is included ECG data. When I look at the plot of whole data, I have an even and normal heartbeat. But for 5 minutes during 10 hour data, suddenly the amplitude of the heart beats decreases dramatically. And this has made my signal processing too difficult because I need ( for instance) a suitable treshhold of amplitude to detect the peaks. I don't know what is your kind recommendation for signal1 and signal2 in my case?

Comment: Well I am new user here and I am not allowed to add a picture to clear my question :)

Comment: @Ana but you are allowed to post a link to it! I will put the image there then