# Amplify two signals in the same proportion

Tags: matlab, signals

I have two audio signals that I want to amplify in order to collect informations and compare them. I want both to be defined between -1 and 1 without changing their original shape.

I already tried this [Strengthening the low amplitude signal using Matlab WITHOUT changing the original shape of the signal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26716558/strengthening-the-low-amplitude-signal-using-matlab-without-changing-the-origina) but it doesn't seem to work in my case.

My values are defined like this :

```
[y1,fs1] = audioread(myfile1);
[y2,fs2] = audioread(myfile2);
```

And here are my signals :

[image]

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are looking to normalize your signal, which means....divide everything by the maximum of the absolute maximum/minimum....

your code should look something like:

```
 normalizey1 = y1./ (max(abs(max(y1)) ,abs(min(y1)) ));
 normalizey2 = y2./ (max(abs(max(y2)) ,abs(min(y2)) ));
```

There is an alternative to normalizing your signal. It is done by dividing by the standard deviation - the Unit Variance Normalization - it is often times more useful when comparing signals.

Comment: Yes it's a kind of normalization but I would like both signals to be included between -1 and 1 but with the same amplitude differencies and properties. I don't konw if you get what I mean.

Comment: @Kenwa this will make both of your signals to be between -1 and 1 with the same variations - so the signal itself is unaltered.

Comment: Ah ok, I thought it was like the version I saw before but I just tested it and it seems to work. Thank you.